# unable to connect mongodb database to localhost it showing not connected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

mongoose.connect( DB, {useNewUrlParser: true,
useCreateIndex: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useFindAndModify:false
}).then(() => {
console.log(`connection successful`);
}).catch((err) =>console.log(`no connection`));

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are passing wrong dbURL your url should look like this

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster_name>.<dbid>.mongodb.net/<Database_Name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Try this

```
   const dbURL = Your mongoDb url
   mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(result => console.log('connected to db'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```